# How to implement a transparent gradient on sides in RN?

Tags: user-interface, react-native

I want to make smooth transparent sides like this:

[image]
[image]

There is the container (`View`) (blue border) that contains `ScrollView`. The container has the transparent gradient on both sides. How to implement that?